# Why CGO can't directly call function pointer in C?

Tags: go, cgo

Defined in C

```c
typedef err_t(* netif_input_fn) (struct pbuf *p, struct netif *inp);
```

Run in GO

```golang
// netif.input is function pointer defined in C
netif.input(buf, netif)
// got error: cannot call non-function netif.input (type _Ctype_netif_input_fn)
```

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44020148/492773) can help.

Comment: @kichik I want to know why CGO doesn't make it easier to allow direct calls.

Comment: Why CGO regards function pointer as non-function? Maybe this title is more accurate.

Comment: It's just not supported right now. That's the only reason the documentation states.

Comment: A Go function is more than a pointer to code. If you take an address of a method it also stores the address of the "object" assoc. with the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CGO function in Go is a C function which needs special treatment to take care of its stack.

A function in Go (aka. goroutine) starts with a small stack size (2 kB) and this stack will be expanded or shrunk automatically. While a CGO function can't benefit from this facility, its initial stack size is 2MB on most operating systems and will be executed on a different stack (g0 stack). So the Go runtime can't treat a CGO function as a normal Go function (goroutine) and calls it directly.